# Proving an equation about exponential of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

> Let $A, B$ be $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that
>   $$[A,[A,B]]=[B,[A,B]] = 0$$
>
> Show
>   $$e^{\epsilon A}Be^{-\epsilon A} = B + \epsilon[A,B]$$

Then, I have to show the equation below. Here $[A, B]$ is equal to $AB-BA$ and $\epsilon$ is a real parameter. I can't find a way to show the equation below... Could anyone explain to me in detail?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry.  I misread the question.

Comment: Try using $[A,[A,B]] = 0$ to justify
$\frac{d}{d\epsilon} \left[ e^{\epsilon A} B e^{-\epsilon A} \right] = e^{\epsilon A}[A,B]e^{-\epsilon A} = e^{\epsilon A} e^{-\epsilon A} [A,B] = [A,B]$.

Comment: I like the argument proposed by @achillehui as well.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Proof}$. Since 
$$
e^{\varepsilon A} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(\varepsilon A)^k}{k!} 
= 1 + \varepsilon A + \frac{\varepsilon^2 A^2}{2!} + 
\frac{\varepsilon^3 A^3}{3!} + \ldots,  
$$ 
we have 
$$
e^{-\varepsilon A} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-\varepsilon A)^k}{k!} 
= 1 - \varepsilon A + \frac{\varepsilon^2 A^2}{2!} - 
\frac{\varepsilon^3 A^3}{3!} + \ldots.  
$$ 
So 
\begin{align*}
e^{\varepsilon A} B e^{-\varepsilon A} 
&= \left(1 + \varepsilon A + \frac{\varepsilon^2 A^2}{2!} + 
\frac{\varepsilon^3 A^3}{3!} + \ldots\right)B \left( 1 - \varepsilon A + \frac{\varepsilon^2 A^2}{2!} - 
\frac{\varepsilon^3 A^3}{3!} + \ldots\right) \\ 
&= \left(1 + \varepsilon A + \frac{\varepsilon^2 A^2}{2!} + 
\frac{\varepsilon^3 A^3}{3!} + \ldots\right) \left( B - \varepsilon B A + \frac{\varepsilon^2 B A^2}{2!} - 
\frac{\varepsilon^3 B A^3}{3!} + \ldots \right) \\ 
&= B + \varepsilon (AB-BA) + 2! \varepsilon^2 (A^2B-2ABA + BA^2) 
+3! \varepsilon^3[A,  [A,[A,B]] ]
+ \ldots \\ 
&= B + \varepsilon [A,B] + 2! \varepsilon^2 [A,[A,B]] +3! \varepsilon^3[A,  [A,[A,B]] ]
+ \ldots \\ 
&= B + \varepsilon [A,B] 
\end{align*}
since $[A,[A,B]]= A(AB-BA)-(AB-BA)A=A^2B-2ABA + BA^2=0$. $\hspace{2cm}\square$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(t)=\exp(t A)\, B \exp(-t A)$, an analytic matrix valued function of $t$ in a neighborhood of $t=0$.  Clearly $f(0) = B.$  Verify $f'(t) = [A,f(t)]$, $f''(t)=[A,f'(t)]$, and so on: $f^{(k)}(t) = [A,f^{(k-1)}(t)]$.

Now evaluate all these derivatives at $t=0$, and assemble them into a Taylor series:$$f(t) = \sum_{n\ge0} \frac{t^n}{n!} f^{(k)}(0).$$

By the foregoing, $f(0) = B$ and $f'(0) = [A,B]$.  Now $f''(0)=[A,[A,B]]$, which vanishes  by hypothesis. By induction, $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n>2$.